# Jquery firing function once per element

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, toggle

So, I have a small table with some content, which with the click of a button can be expanded to show a container div with extra content.

I'm trying to tie a function to this action, but when I do, the function seems to get fired once per number of table row.

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jtby9c12/

Table:

```
<button id="toggle-descriptions-button">+</button>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-header-1">Download</th>
      <th class="table-header-2">Size</th>
      <th class="table-header-3">Notes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column-1">Item
            <div class="div-container" style="display: block;">
                <div class="div-gallery">
                    <img src="#">
                    <br style="clear: both">
                </div>
                <div class="div-description">Description Text</div>
            </div>
        </td>
      <td class="column-2">1.2MB</td>
      <td class="column-3">Note</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

*The actual table contains 22 rows and descriptions, this just shows the structure sample.

Jquery:

```
var descriptions = $(".div-container")
var descButton = $("#toggle-descriptions-button")

descButton.click(function(){
    console.log("Button Clicked!")
    descriptions.toggle(400, function() {
        console.log("I'm a fucntion!")
    });
});
```

As you can see, it calls the function 22 times, and I'm trying to get it to call just once.

[image]

I'm looking to get a single call back for the function, it's one state change for all descriptions, I only need one return.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah. I misread the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can use the `promise()` returned from the `toggle()` calls. Attach a `done()` event handler to it, which will fire after all the promises have been resolved:

```js
var $descriptions = $(".div-container")
var $descButton = $("#toggle-descriptions-button")

$descButton.click(function() {
  console.log("Button Clicked!")
  $descriptions.toggle(400).promise().done(function() {
    console.log("I'm a function!")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle-descriptions-button">+</button>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-header-1">Download</th>
      <th class="table-header-2">Size</th>
      <th class="table-header-3">Notes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="column-1">Item
        <div class="div-container" style="display: none;">
          <div class="div-gallery">
            <img src="#">
            <br style="clear: both">
          </div>
          <div class="div-description">Description Text</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="column-2">1.2MB</td>
      <td class="column-3">Note</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="column-1">Item
        <div class="div-container" style="display: none;">
          <div class="div-gallery">
            <img src="#">
            <br style="clear: both">
          </div>
          <div class="div-description">Description Text</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="column-2">1.2MB</td>
      <td class="column-3">Note</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="column-1">Item
        <div class="div-container" style="display: none;">
          <div class="div-gallery">
            <img src="#">
            <br style="clear: both">
          </div>
          <div class="div-description">Description Text</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="column-2">1.2MB</td>
      <td class="column-3">Note</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: HA! Amazing, this accomplishes exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for pointing this out!